# TLE when solving "Removing duplicates from unsorted linked list" using maps in c++

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, c++14

I am trying to solve the [removing duplicates from unsorted linked list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-duplicates-from-an-unsorted-linked-list/) problem on GFG using maps. I have figured out the accepted solution using insert and find commands:

```
Node * removeDuplicates( Node *head) 
{
 // your code goes here
 map <int, int> duplicates;
 
 Node* curr=head;
 Node* prev=NULL;
 while(curr){
     
     if(duplicates.find(curr->data)==duplicates.end()){
         duplicates.insert({curr->data,1});
         prev=curr;
         
     }
     else{
         
         prev->next=curr->next;
         delete(curr);
     }
     curr=prev->next;
 }
 return head;
}
```

But another approach I tried earlier is giving TLE for submission, even though it works fine for example test case. I have tried to implement the same idea as above but in a slightly different way. Can anyone help me out with this?

```
Node * removeDuplicates( Node *head) 
{
 map <int, int> duplicates;
 Node* temp=head;
 while(temp){
     duplicates[temp->data]=1;
     temp=temp->next;
 }
 
 Node* curr=head;
 Node* prev=NULL;
 while(curr){
     
     if(duplicates[curr->data]==1){
         duplicates[curr->data]=0;
         prev=curr;
         
     }
     else{
         
         prev->next=curr->next;
         delete(curr);
     }
     curr=prev->next;
 }
 return head;
}
```

Comment: For the uninitiated, what's a TLE?

Comment: The first thing to try is unordered_map instead of map. unordered_set should be better still.

Comment: @Stef TLE = Time Limit Exceeded. In algorithmic problems, it means the solution works too long for some test case conforming to the constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with the 2nd solution.

- your running through a linked list twice, don't do this if possible.
- unordered_map might be much faster as already mentioned in the commented
- your looking more in the duplicates in the 2nd solution, 3 vs. 2.

Either of the above could further cause cache congestion slowing things down further.

Answer (score 0):

- Take the bool data type far value instead of int so you don't have to initialize the value of a map.
- Instead of taking an ordered map use the unordered map which is relatively faster.
- Here is the optimized code.

```
 
    
        Node *removeDuplicates(Node *head)
        {
            Node *curr = head;
            Node *prev = NULL;

            if (curr == NULL)
                return NULL;

            unordered_map visited;

            while (curr != NULL)
            {

                if (visited[curr->data])
                {
                    Node *temp = curr;
                    curr = curr->next;
                    delete (temp);
                    prev->next = curr;
                }
                else
                {
                    visited[curr->data] = true;
                    prev = curr;
                    curr = curr->next;
                }
                
            }
            return head;
        }
```